# Show list of users in left bottom windows credential provider

Tags: c++, windows, credential-providers, winlogon

I am writing custom windows credential provider using c++ with the help of sample provided by windows [CredentialProvider2](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CredentialProvider)

I modified CredentialCount and CredentialAt in provider class to return 3 users. Those 3 users appear below sign-in options link. I expect them to display left bottom of the screen.

```
HRESULT CSampleProvider::GetCredentialCount(
    _Out_ DWORD *pdwCount,
    _Out_ DWORD *pdwDefault,
    _Out_ BOOL *pbAutoLogonWithDefault)
{
    *pdwDefault = CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_NO_DEFAULT;
    *pbAutoLogonWithDefault = FALSE;

    if (_fRecreateEnumeratedCredentials)
    {
        _fRecreateEnumeratedCredentials = false;
        _ReleaseEnumeratedCredentials();
        _CreateEnumeratedCredentials();
    }

    *pdwCount = 3;

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT CSampleProvider::GetCredentialAt(
    DWORD dwIndex,
    _Outptr_result_nullonfailure_ ICredentialProviderCredential **ppcpc)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_INVALIDARG;
    *ppcpc = nullptr;

    if(ppcpc){
        hr = _pCredential->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(ppcpc));
    }
    return hr;
}
```

This is what I get
[image: I get this]

But **I want to display the list of users in the left bottom of the screen**. I will be a great help if you suggest me the changes are required to make it display left bottom on the screen?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The standard layout follows a deliberate design, keeping related information in close proximity. Moving the list of users away from the password field just makes the UI less obvious.

Comment: You are missing the concept of credential provider ecosystem. Each of users you enumerate must correspond to the user able to login to a system you are testing on. Then the WinLogon will draw inside of each user's screen your provider's logo.